# python - Plot a bar-plot with grouped data as x-axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

So I have 2 lists, c_val and d_val which I group together in a list called tlt:

```
c_val = [0.1, 1, 10, 100]
d_val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
tlt = []
for c in c_val:
    for d in d_val:
        tlt.append((c,v))
        
outcome = [0.43, 0.48, 0.50, 0.45, 1, 1.40, 1.30, 1.80, 1.9, 1.10, 1.34, 1.2, 1.24, 0.49, 0.2, 0.93]
```

Both tlt and outcome lists have 16 values now and I want to plot a barplot with tlt values on the x-axis and outcome on the y-axis, but I get a key error which is due to the fact that the x-axis is a tupple.

I am trying to do this with seaborn, but I don't mind doing it with matplotlib if a solution is possible there.

```
sns.barplot(tlt, accuracies)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I added it. I am trying to plot it through seaborn

Comment: You could create `tlt` with strings: `tlt.append(str((c, d)))`.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: You could also create a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'cval': np.repeat(c_val, 4), 'dval': np.tile(d_val, 4), 'outcome': outcome})` and then a grouped bar plot: `sns.barplot(data=df, x='cval', y='outcome', orient='v', hue='dval')`

Answer (score 0):

You can plot it with matplotlib like this

```
c_val = [0.1, 1, 10, 100]
d_val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
tlt = []
for c in c_val:
    for d in d_val:
        tlt.append(str((c,d)))
        
outcome = [0.43, 0.48, 0.50, 0.45, 1, 1.40, 1.30, 1.80, 1.9, 1.10, 1.34, 1.2, 1.24, 0.49, 0.2, 0.93]


plt.bar(tlt, outcome, width=0.8, bottom=None)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Output

[image]